# Startindex swift 3 issue

Tags: swift, swift3

I get a startIndex error. The error is "Value of type 'string.index'(aka'string.characterview.index')has no member'advanced". Heres code and an image of the error.

```
public override final var secureTextEntry: Bool {
    didSet {
        let textFieldArray: [UITextField?] = [numberInputTextField, cvcTextField, monthTextField, yearTextField]
        textFieldArray.forEach({$0?.isSecureTextEntry = secureTextEntry})
    }
}
```

[Image of Error of isfirstresponder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UY6Ae.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In swift 3 you can no longer use advanced, successor or predecessor, instead you need to use

```
let indexAfter = someString.index(after: someIndex)
let indexBefore = someString.index(before: someIndex)
let anyOtherIndex = someString.index(someIndex, offsetBy: distance)
```

so your code should look like this

```
let index = (hasOverflow) ? 
text.index(text.startIndex, offsetBy: expectedInputLength) :
text.index(text.startIndex, offsetBy: text.characters.count)
```

As a side note,

```
text.index(text.startIndex, offsetBy: text.characters.count)
```

Is actually the same as

```
text.endIndex
```

So you can use this instead

```
let index = (hasOverflow) ? 
text.index(text.startIndex, offsetBy: expectedInputLength) :
text.endIndex
```

Comment: how would you fix the other error.

Comment: I get the same error with a different function

Comment: Using the same function: text.index(text.startIndex, offsetBy: fromInclusively) and text.index(text.startIndex, offsetBy: toExclusively) respectively

Comment: Have a look at the duplicate question linked above; they explain it well :)

Comment: could you help fix it please, I looked at it and it didn't solve my problem. Could you please help fix it

Comment: its telling me unresolved use of identifier "text"

Comment: Ah sorry, use self instead of text

Comment: theres an image above

Comment: where do i put the self

Comment: could i get your help with something else

Comment: Yeah sure I'll give it a shot :)

Comment: I get another error. I reposted, can you see the image above should I change the isfirstresponder to

Comment: could you check it out and see what the problem is

Comment: I get a "property does not override any property from its superclass" error. How do I fix it. Thanks

Comment: Search for the error message on Stack Overflow, I very rarely can't find answer with a couple searches. It's amazing how much info there is on here. There will be a better answer than I can give here :)

Comment: I searched a lot and found nothing. I'm telling yo the truth